# PySpark when condition not working for smaller string values

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, case

I'm trying to change the column values using `when` condition.

The `when` condition is working well and the columns are getting updated with the corresponding literal values for both "DJOUR" and "DECBA" which are 5 char length, but the `when` condition is not working for the other values like "DEP" ,"BUY", "WITH"... which are less than 5 char length.

Why the `when` condition is not able to identify the smaller length string values?
Also, please correct me if I'm using the `when` condition incorrectly.

```py
df1 = df.withColumn("selling_type", when(col("selling_type") == "BUY", lit("ABCDEF1"))\
        .when(col("selling_type") == "CJOUR", lit("ABCDEF2"))\
        .when(col("selling_type") == "DEP", lit("ABCDEF3"))\   # not working
        .when(col("selling_type") == "DIV", lit("ABCDEF4"))\   # not working
        .when(col("selling_type") == "DJOUR", lit("ABCDEF5"))\ # working
        .when(col("selling_type") == "DECBA", lit("ABCDEF6"))\ # working
        .when(col("selling_type") == "MFEE", lit("ABCDEF7"))\
        .when(col("selling_type") == "SELL", lit("ABCDEF8"))\
        .when(col("selling_type") == "TEFRA", lit("ABCDEF9"))\
        .when(col("selling_type") == "WITH", lit("ABCDEF10"))\
        .otherwise(col("selling_type")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.when()` does work with strings of arbitrary length. Could you check whether your columns really contain **"DEP"** without any spaces at the beginning / end etc.?

The following code works for me:

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(["CJOUR", "DEP"], StringType())
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

>>> df = df.withColumnRenamed("value", "selling_type")
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lit
>>> df1 = df.withColumn("selling_type", trim(col("selling_type")).withColumn("selling_type", when(col("selling_type") == "BUY", lit("ABCDEF1")) 
                        .when(col("selling_type") == "CJOUR", lit("ABCDEF2"))
                        .when(col("selling_type") == "DEP", lit("ABCDEF3"))  
                        .when(col("selling_type") == "DIV", lit("ABCDEF4"))
                        .when(col("selling_type") == "DJOUR", lit("ABCDEF5"))
                        .when(col("selling_type") == "DECBA", lit("ABCDEF6"))
                        .when(col("selling_type") == "MFEE", lit("ABCDEF7"))
                        .when(col("selling_type") == "SELL", lit("ABCDEF8"))
                        .when(col("selling_type") == "TEFRA", lit("ABCDEF9"))
                        .when(col("selling_type") == "WITH", lit("ABCDEF10"))
                        .otherwise(col("selling_type")))
>>> 
>>> df1.show()
+------------+                                                                  
|selling_type|
+------------+
|     ABCDEF2|
|     ABCDEF3|
+------------+
```

Comment: I checked my columns, there are not spaces at the beginning/ end.
Is there any other alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: I can not think of a workaround, but this should definitely work. Could you provide some data to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Instead of "when" I used "regexp_replace" and it worked! I'm still not not sure why it didn't worked with "when". Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: The regexp_replace removed whitespaces. So you essentially had whitespaces. I've updated my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, it will trim all the visible and invisible white space from both sides of your strings. Also, you can change all the repetitive `when` clauses with a simpler `replace` method.

Input dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("BUY",), ("CJOUR",), ("DEP",), ("DIV",), ("DJOUR",), ("DECBA",), ("MFEE",), ("SELL",), ("TEFRA",), ("WITH",)], ["selling_type"])
```

Script:

```py
df = df.withColumn("selling_type", F.regexp_replace("selling_type", r"^\s+|\s+$", ""))
df = df.replace({
    "BUY": "ABCDEF1",
    "CJOUR": "ABCDEF2",
    "DEP": "ABCDEF3",
    "DIV": "ABCDEF4",
    "DJOUR": "ABCDEF5",
    "DECBA": "ABCDEF6",
    "MFEE": "ABCDEF7",
    "SELL": "ABCDEF8",
    "TEFRA": "ABCDEF9",
    "WITH": "ABCDEF10",
}, subset=["selling_type"])

df.show()
# +------------+
# |selling_type|
# +------------+
# |     ABCDEF1|
# |     ABCDEF2|
# |     ABCDEF3|
# |     ABCDEF4|
# |     ABCDEF5|
# |     ABCDEF6|
# |     ABCDEF7|
# |     ABCDEF8|
# |     ABCDEF9|
# |    ABCDEF10|
# +------------+
```

Comment: I used "regexp_replace" and it worked well!, thanks for your answer.